# On a constrained trace minimisation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Suppose $S = \pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0\\ 0&1}$, $W$ is a $3\times3$ covariance matrix, which could be regarded as fixed.

I need to find a $2\times 3$ matrix $Q$ that minimizes
$$
\operatorname{trace}\left[(SQ)W(SQ)^T\right]
$$
subject to $SQS=S$.

Please help me to solve this issue!!!...

Thanks

Comment: What are the dimensions of $W$ and $Q$?

Comment: $W$ is 3x3, $Q$ is 2x3.

Comment: I think you have overseen the constraint $SQS=S$.

Comment: @Ert I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, all matrices here are real. If $S\in M_{m+n,\,n}(\mathbb R)$ has full column rank, the equation $SQS=S$ actually has a unique solution: since $Q$ has the same size as $S^T$ and the latter has full row rank, $Q=XS^T$ for some square matrix $X\in M_n(\mathbb R)$. Therefore $SQS=S$ then implies that $S^TSXS^TS=S^TS$, i.e. $X=(S^TS)^{-1}$. Consequently, $Q=(S^TS)^{-1}S^T$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help and effort. Greatly appreciated it. I am not a good mathematician. So can you help me to clarify few things. How did you say that, $Q = J +xv'$. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to generalize that relationship to, a bigger matrix, such as $ S = \pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\\ 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}$??

Comment: I like the elegant solution of user1551 but I think in general it is hard to find the solution analytically. Then, you have to do some numerical optimization.

Comment: I don't think. Feel like there should be a way. Because matrix can be rearranged to have $S$ sub matrices. But don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :).

Comment: I was trying to use similar set of arguments for a different $S = \pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}$ and $W=I$ assuming that $S = \pmatrix{C\\B}$ where $B=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}$. For this case $J=\pmatrix{0 & & B'}$ and $V' = \pmatrix{I & & -CB'}$. But the solution I got for $Q$ doesn't simplifies to $QS = I$, even though I start with something similar to this. Could you please explain is this a special case this won't work? Thanks.

Comment: Why it is essential to have last four rows as $I_{4}$? Can'we generalize it where identity matrix at the bottom of $S$ is a special case?

Comment: I am wondering any reason why it is not the case. Is it because $BB' = I$ (always), so $B'$ is the generalized inverse of B, which is not unique.

Comment: What I was referring to as $BB'=I$ is the above particular choice I have given. I do agree that your solution assumes $B'B=I$. I followed similar set of steps for this new case I was able to get $Q=\pmatrix{X&Y}$. To satisfy $QS=I$, $Y=B' - XCB'$. This leads new $J = \pmatrix{0 & & B'}$ and $V' = \pmatrix{I & & -CB'}$. Then rest of the arguments are similar. But the resulting solution doesn't make $QS=I$, though I start with it.

Comment: I agree with this solution. But the previous one was elegant because inverse that has to be taken is of lower dimension than the new representation. It is useful when the $S$ matrix is large. Unfortunately unless $B=I$, these alternative representations do not coincide.

Comment: I think $Q$ should be a function of $W$??

Comment: @shani In general, yes, but in your case, the constraint $SQS=S$ has only one feasible solution ($Q=$ Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $S$), so it doesn't matter what $W$ is.

Answer (score 1):

I have devided my answer in two parts. First I introduce the formulation. Second, I consider the optimization.

1) Formulation:
For simplicity let me rewrite your problem in vector form and formulate it as a quadratic programming problem of the form
$$ \min_q q^T R q ~~~~~~{\rm    s.t.}~~~~~~ Aq = s. $$

The following definitions are necessary to forumulate the constraints. For convencience, we consider $S^TQ^TS^T=S^T$ instead of $SQS=S$.

- $q={\rm vec}(Q^T)$, i.e. if $Q^T$ consists of the column vectors of $Q^T = [q_1,q_2]$, then $q$ is the vector which contains both.
- $s={\rm vec}(S^T)$.
- $A = S \otimes S^T$ where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product  we can then rewrite $S^TQ^TS^T=S^T$ equivalently as $Aq=s$.

Let us now rewrite the target function:

- Let us define the matrix $P=QS$ with the three row vectors $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ and we have $trace[SQW(SQ)^T]=\sum_{i=1}^3 p_i W p_i^T$.
- Moreover, we define $p = [p_1,p_2,p_2] = {\rm vec}^T\{(SQ)^T\}$ and $V = \rm{blockdiag}[W,W,W]$. ($V$ is the blockdiagonal matrix which has three $W$s on its diagonal) to have $trace[SQW(SQ)^T]=\sum_{i=1}^3 p_i W p_i^T = p V p^T$.
- Exploiting the propoerties of the Kronecker product, we have $p^T = {\rm vec}\{(SQ)^T\} = (S \otimes \mathbf{I})q $ where $I$ is the 3x3 identiy matrix.
- Finally we can rewrite $trace[SQW(SQ)^T]=q^T R q$ where $R = (S \otimes \mathbf{I})^T V (S \otimes \mathbf{I})$

2) Optimization: Having the optimization problem in vector, it is straight forward to solve it, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming. Note that, even though $A$ is 6x6 and $s$ also has length 6 there are still degrees of freedom left for the optimization as $A$ does not have full rank (I checked this with Matlab).

One possible algorithm to solve the optimization problem is explained here:
Let $q_0 $ be a particular solution to the equation system such that $Aq_0 = s$ and let $q_1$ element of the null space of $A$ such that $A q_1 = 0$. Let $B $ contain a basis for the null space (B can be found by using SVD for example) such that $q_1$ can be expressed as $q_1 = B x$, where $x$ is an arbitrary vector such that $ABx = 0$. Then the quadratic programming problem can be formulated in respect to the free variable $x$ as

$$ \min_{q_1} (q_1 + q_0)^T R( q_1 +q_0) = \min_{x} (Bx + q_0)^T R( Bx+q_0)= \min_x x^T B^T R B x + 2 x^T B^T R q_0 + const.  $$ 
Note that $q_0$ is fix here!

The solution $x^\star$ to this problem is given by $x^\star= (B^T R B)^{-1} B^T R q_0$.

With $x^\star$ you find $q_1$, together with $q_0$ you find the matrix $Q$.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help and the valuable time. This might sounds like stupid. Is it possible to do it without optimization.

Comment: Please post your solution! I can't wait to see it!

Comment: I have no idea how to implement this procedure as how to calculate $B$?

Comment: Compute the svd of $A$: In matlab [U,D,K] = svd(A) where D is a diagonal matrix. As $A$ does not have full rank, some of it's diagonal entries will be zero. B is the sub matrix of K corresponding to these zero-entries. In matlab, you find this matrix with B = K(:,find(diag(D)<10^(-6))).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this applicable for any size of $S$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it out. It would be great if you could briefly explain me the optimization section (I mean the theory behind it) I have no idea about null space and stuff. Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe my explanation was too difficult. The important thing is there is a straight forward way to deal with the stated optimization problem in vector form. For further reading see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: Thanks Ert. Since you have not put much restrictions on $S$ I guess it should work with the bigger matrix as I have mentioned under 'user1551'?

Comment: Yes. Let me ask you one question: For what application do you need the optimization?

Comment: It is for computing prediction intervals. I need to find the optimal set of weights $Q$ by minimizing the trace expression as given in the question.